# How to connect 2 cuboids in a "T" shape

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges

I'm not looking for the basic "Press F". I need both meshes to be connected with a correct topology. Their edge positions are set up properly, it's just that a lot of the vertexes aren't actually connected to anything, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to quickly fix my oversight, or how would I go about fixing it the manual way?

Answer (score 3):

Make 2 loop cuts on the vertical shaft (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), bring them close to the vertices of the horizontal shaft (as Julian points out in the comments, once you accept the position of a loop cut, you can still readjust by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> twice), when the vertices of the two shafts are nearly touching each other (green lines on the image), select all 8 vertices (you can do it easily in *Wireframe* mode, press <kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>W</kbd>) and press <kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>B</kbd> (*Merge by distance*) - the vertices should now be connected.

Remember to remove the inner face (marked red) for proper shading - you can do it easily in *Wireframe* mode or by hiding one of the external faces first.

[image]

Comment: "bring it close to the vertices of the horizontal shaft" by edge sliding with [g+g].

Comment: If we're working with exact sizes, will this produce a slight distortion? How could I make sure the produced connection is exactly, say, 3x3m?